# How to search nested object by following JSLint

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jslint

I have my object structured as below and I want to find the product with provided ID.

```
0 :{
   id: 0,
   title: 'xxxx',
   url: "www.test.com"
   quantity: 100
},
1 :{
   id: 10,
   title: 'xxxx',
   url: "www.test.com"
   quantity: 100
},
// and so on...
```

In order to search nested attribute within the object, I have written the below function:

```
export const selectProductById = (state, productId) => {
   const obj_index = Object.keys(state.products).find(function(idx) {
      if (state.products[idx].id == productId) {
         return idx;
      }
   }

   return state.products[obj_index]
}
```

This works but I will always get a warning during compilation of my react app.
`Expected '===' and instead saw '=='`

But if I change this into `===` the code will not work anymore, does anyone knows how to change this so that it follows JSLint rules ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the `productId` is not a number. Cast it to a number first:

```
if (state.products[idx].id === Number(productId)) {
```

But you should return a truthy or falsey value from the `.find` callback, *not* something that you're iterating over (since you may not be sure whether it's truthy or falsey, and it's potentially confusing). Return the result of the `===` comparison instead:

```
const { products } = state;
const obj_index = Object.keys(products).find(
  key => products[key].id === Number(productId)
);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help! Yes, I originally was using something similar as the above but I didn't realized the productId is not a number, so heck it didn't work so I could only return index to double check if the code is working as expected.

Comment: I guess it somehow converted into something else that is not a number during fetch hence I didn't find out why ```===``` never worked. I will accept your reply as the answer once the time limit is lifted. Thank you so much for helping out on this.